# How to check if datagridview cell is Null

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I want to display a message if the value of cell of my datagridview is Null.
Please advise how to do it.
Thanks and best regards,

Furqan

Comment: Hi, a bit too generic question, you should tell us at least how you are filling the grid, where is the data coming from? I ask because I believe you should check for null the data not the grid cell, unless you are working in unbound mode.

Comment: Is your `DataGridView` bound to a data source?

Comment: Thanks, the data is being entered directly, by typing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to check if the [`Value` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.value.aspx) of the [`DataGridViewCell`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.aspx) is `Nothing` (the equivalent of `null` in C#).

You can do that with the following code:

```
If myDataGridView.CurrentCell.Value Is Nothing Then
    MessageBox.Show("Cell is empty")
Else
    MessageBox.Show("Cell contains a value")
End If
```

If you want to inform the user when they try to leave the cell that it has been left empty, you need to use similar code in the [`CellValidating`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvalidating.aspx) event handler method. For example:

```
Private Sub myDataGridView_CellValidating(ByVal sender As Object,
               ByVal e As DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs)
               Handles myDataGridView.CellValidating
    If myDataGridView.Item(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).Value Is Nothing Then
        ' Show the user a message
        MessageBox.Show("You have left the cell empty")

        ' Fail validation (prevent them from leaving the cell)
        e.Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: recommend using **e.FormattedValue** while in CellValidating

Comment: EDIT: This doesn't work. Use `If String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.FormattedValue) Then` instead.