# How to check If a DataGridView column value is null or 0 in c#?

Tags: c#, if-statement, datagridview, messagebox

I'm developing a windows form application or a books store using c#.This datagridview behave as a sales cart. Data load to datagridview from a sql database.

1st column 0,column 1,column 2,column 3, column 4 and column 5 consist with BookName, ISBN_No,Quantity,UnitPrice, Total and stock.When I select BookName, ISBN_No and Unit_price will autofill. I would like to know how to check if a datagridview cell value contains a zero or null.I tried following code. But it didn't work.

```
if(Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[dataGridView1.Columns[5].Index].Value) == 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Quantiy is not Available");
                }
```

This didn't display anything even I enter a zero value into this datagridvie cell.

Comment: When you entered `0` what was the value of `row.Cells[dataGridView1.Columns[5].Index].Value`? `row.Cells[dataGridView1.Columns[4].Index].Value`? `row.Cells[dataGridView1.Columns[6].Index].Value`? Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4942593/how-to-check-if-datagridview-cell-is-null help?

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that the awkward line of code…

```
Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[dataGridView1.Columns[5].Index].Value)
```

may be throwing you off. The `Convert.ToInt32` is going to return zero (0) if…

```
row.Cells[dataGridView1.Columns[5].Index].Value
```

returns null… therefore, using this construct is not going to help you distinguish between a `null` value and a zero (`0`) value as BOTH values will return zero (0).

The code WILL throw a `FormatException` exception if `Value` is not a valid number. It will NOT throw an exception if the value is null.

To help, I am confident you will need to break this down to three (3) parts.
1)  Check for a `null` value.
2)  If not null, check for a valid number.
3)  If the number is valid, check if it is zero (0).

The “awkward” portion of the `if` statement is…

```
dataGridView1.Columns[5].Index  ???
```

this is “always” going to return “5”. Therefore, the statement…

```
Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[dataGridView1.Columns[5].Index].Value
```

could be rewritten as…

```
Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[5].Value
```

With that said, below is the code that will help distinguish between null values, non-number values and lastly if the value is zero. As Derinder suggest, using the `int32.TryParse` method is a better option.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  FillGrid();
}

private void FillGrid() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add("C0R" + i, "C1R" + i, "C2R" + i, "C3R" + i, "C4R" + i, i);
  }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex];
  if (row.Cells[5].Value != null) {
    if (Int32.TryParse(row.Cells[5].Value.ToString(), out Int32 numvalue)) {
      if (numvalue == 0) {
        MessageBox.Show("Quantity/Value is not null and is equal to zero 0");
      }
      else {
        MessageBox.Show("Quantity/Value is not null, is a valid number but it is NOT equal to zero 0. Its value is: " + numvalue);
      }
    }
    else {
      MessageBox.Show("Quantity/Value is not null but it is not a valid number. Its value is: " + row.Cells[5].Value.ToString());
    }
  }
  else {
    MessageBox.Show("Quantity/Value is null...");
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you can solve your Problem with "int32.TryParse" method. 
Other advantage is that it doesn't not throw exception like convert.toint32 ,if it doesn't succeed.
You are always on safer side.